# Design Pattern for late binding class (without switch case for class assignment)

Tags: oop, design-patterns, c#-3.0

I have a base class where all common functions are written. I many classes which override this functions by virtual keyword. Like,

```
public class Base
{
   public virtual void sample()
   {
     ..............
   }
}

public class a : Base
{
   public override sample()
   {

   }
}

public class implement
{

   public void ToSample()
   {
     Base baseclass = new Base();

     Switch(test)
     {
        case a: baseclass = a();
         break;

        case b: baseclass = b();
        break; 
     }

    baseclass.sample();
   }

}
```

This perfect code for current situation but now I have more class to be assign in switch case. It is not good practice for adding huge amount of cases so I want something that automatically assign child class.

Is anybody know something to be implement ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the answer but this sounds like something you could use a Dependency Injector for. Take a look at StructureMap.

Comment: Thanks @JamesCulshaw it is seeing same as what I want but when i am googling it is mostly give with MVC. Is it possible with Web asp.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, you can decouple the implementation by using [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). Note however, that in some cases you have no choice but doing that kind of switch (e.g. when you need to create a class based on a text received in a socket). In such cases the important thing is to always keep the switch statement encapsulated in one method and make your objects rely on it (or, in other words, don't copy-and-paste it everywhere :)). The idea here is too keep your system isolated from a potentially harmful code. Of course that if you add a new class you will have to go and modify that method, however you will only have to do it in one time and in one specific place.

Another approach that I have seen (and sometimes used) is to build a mapping between values an classes. So, if your class-creation switch depends on an integer code, you basically create a mapping between codes and classes. What you are doing here is turning a "static" switch into a dynamic behavior, since you can change the mappings contents at any time and thus alter the way your program behaves. A typical implementation would be something like (sorry for the pseudocode, I'm not familiar with C#):

```
public class implement
{

   public void ToSample()
   {
     class = this.mapping.valueForKey(test);
     Base baseclass = new class();
     baseclass.sample();
   }
}
```

Note however that for this example to work you need [reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29) support, which varies according to the language you are using (again, sorry but I don't know the C# specifics).

Finally, you can also check the [creational](http://www.oodesign.com/creational-patterns/) family of patterns for inspiration regarding object creation issues and some well known forms of solving them.

HTH